# how to build a JsonObject using a particular jsonfromat

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to access an API from my java code. The API only accepts data in the form of a JSON object, but I'm having trouble building a `JsonObject` representation.

What I want to do is use `createObjectBuilder()` to create a `JsonObject` formatted as follows:

```
{
    "user1234@gmail.com": {
        "username" : "user1234@gmail.com",
        "password" : "password1",
        "service" : [ "yourkit" ]
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add(
                                username,
                                Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add("username", username)
                                    .add("password", password)
                                    .add("service", service)
                            ).build();

p.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8")); 
HttpResponse r = c.execute(p);
```

But it doesn't send the correct request to the API.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: May be you are having problems understanding the structure of the in-coming JSON. This link might be helpful to you to be able to view the JSON structure of the incoming JSON => http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: i have executed the request in poster and i got a positive result,what i need is how to build the jason object based on the above mentioned format

Comment: Please format your code, @fresher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an array for service attribute:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)Json.createObjectBuilder()
                        .add(
                            username,
                            Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                .add("username", username)
                                .add("password", password)
                                .add("service",
                                    Json.createArrayBuilder()
                                      .add(service)
                                )
                        ).build();
```

Answer (score 2):

To achive the format you want the variable *service* has to be array of strings.

Comment: i have changed that to
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add(
                                username,
                                Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add("username", username)
                                    .add("password", password)
                                    .add("service", Json.createArrayBuilder().add(service)))
                            ).build();